# Can't edit variable inside a request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request

I'm trying to modify a variable when I'm inside a request. But I don't know why it doesn't get modified.

```
const request = require("request");
var all = JSON.parse(body);
var steamplayer = all['response']['players']['player'][0];
var sgameh = "Nessun gioco";
request({
    url: "https://example.com",
    method : 'GET'
}, function (error, response, body){
    var sgameall = JSON.parse(body);
    var fgame = sgameall['response']['games'].filter(function(item) {
        return item.appid == steamplayer.gameid;
    });
    sgameh = parseFloat(fgame[0].playtime_forever / 60).toFixed(2);
    console.log(sgameh) // THIS WORKS, BUT IT ISN'T WHAT I WANT
})
console.log(sgameh) // SHOULD RETURN A NUMBER, BUT RETURN Nessun gioco
```

Comment: Looks like `sgameh` has two scopes. So both console.log statements are returning values based on the two different scopes of the variable.

Comment: So it works like in the answer even with request ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works correctly and your `sgameh` variable is modified as you want it to be. The `request` function is asynchroneous so

```
console.log(sgameh) // SHOULD RETURN A NUMBER, BUT RETURN Nessun gioco
```

is executed before

```
console.log(sgameh) // THIS WORKS, BUT IT ISN'T WHAT I WANT
```

Comment: So what should i do to adjust this?

Comment: Here is a good [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) @Hamms suggested